# Export Rename Camera Suffix help

Tags: camera

I'm working with the Multi-View to render my character in 8 different views, so my 8 cameras have 8 different names suffix like ("Camera_Idle_Down", "Camera_Idle_DownLeft", "Camera_Idle_Right"...) My problem is that I don't know how to put the frame number in after the suffix when export as png. I already tried rename the cameras to Camera_Idle_Down_##, and does not work. I was trying to find how to put the suffix and the number with camera_## and filename_## but without success.

[image]